# android firebase realtimedatabase Questions(recycler view, onclick button, remove)

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I want the data of item1 to be deleted when the button on item1 is clicked.
but `mDatabase.getReference("Choicestore").child(String.valueOf(arrayList.get(position)));`
I don't know what to do with this part.

[image: database image, I want the data of item1 to be deleted when the button on item1 is clicked. and I want the data of item2 to be deleted when the button on item2 is clicked.]

I want the data of item1 to be deleted when the button on item1 is clicked. and I want the data of item2 to be deleted when the button on item2 is clicked.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ChoicestoreViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    Glide.with(holder.itemView)
            .load(arrayList.get(position).getChoicestore_img())
            .into(holder.choicestore_img);
    holder.choicestore_name.setText("storename : " + arrayList.get(position).getChoicestore_name());
    holder.choicestore_time.setText("opentime : " + arrayList.get(position).getChoicestore_time());
    holder.choicestore_breaktime.setText("breaktime : " +arrayList.get(position).getChoicestore_breaktime());
    holder.choicestore_number.setText("storenumber : " + arrayList.get(position).getChoicestore_number());

    holder.choicestore_delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            dataRef = mDatabase.getReference("Choicestore").child(String.valueOf(arrayList.get(position)));

            dataRef.removeValue();

        }
    });
}
```

---

I coded using the answers below, but I get this error.

---

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Te5zQ.png)

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ChoicestoreViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    Glide.with(holder.itemView)
            .load(arrayList.get(position).getChoicestore_img())
            .into(holder.choicestore_img);
    holder.choicestore_name.setText("매장명 : " + arrayList.get(position).getChoicestore_name());
    holder.choicestore_time.setText("운영시간 : " + arrayList.get(position).getChoicestore_time());
    holder.choicestore_breaktime.setText("브레이크타임 : " +arrayList.get(position).getChoicestore_breaktime());
    holder.choicestore_number.setText("매장번호 : " + arrayList.get(position).getChoicestore_number());

    holder.choicestore_delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            final String NAme= arrayList.get(position).getChoicestore_name();


            dataRef.orderByChild("choicestore_name")
                    .equalTo( NAme )
                    .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                String clubkey = childSnapshot.getKey();

                                Log.d(TAG, "KEY = " + clubkey );


                                childSnapshot.getRef().removeValue();


                            }

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }

                    });
        }
    });



}
```

---

This is the code where the error occurred.

Comment: linked image is  database image, I want the data of choicestore01 to be deleted when the button on item1 is clicked. and I want the data of choicestore02 to be deleted when the button on item2 is clicked.

Comment: Use `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` and get the key. in your case key means choicestore01 and then remove that node

Comment: add this line in onClick method `dataRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference( "Choicestore" );`

Comment: thanks for your help. It's working fine. thanks you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside `holder.choicestore_delete.setOnClickListener`

```
final String NAme= arrayList.get(position).getChoicestore_name();


                            mDatabasesliderRef.orderByChild("choicestore_name")
                                    .equalTo( NAme )
                                    .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                            for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                                String clubkey = childSnapshot.getKey();

                                                Log.d( TAG, "KEY = " + clubkey );


                                                    childSnapshot.getRef().removeValue();


                                            }

                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                        }

                                    });
```

Comment: Hello @titititi , is it worked or not? if it worked accept my answer so it can help others.

Comment: i'm sorry for late.I was late because i am Beginner and I didn't understand the error.